# Enable/Disable field

Tags: apex, lightning, component

this is using Lightning component and apex, i'm working with an API that brings data and auto populate my form, this form have all fields disabled for users not to enter any additional data when a field is brought with information, but in other hand if a field brings with "n/a" or "none" it should let the user complete that field, i tried with disabled attribute with no success, it is there a way to accomplish this? Just using coding. Thanks in advanced!

**EDIT**

I solved this by using JS controller but now have this problem, when i do the first call all the fields that are evaluate with conditional `if` can be edited. Next calls this doesn't happen and works well

here is the code i use :

```
var myvar = component.get("v.sobject.field");  
        if (myvar == 'asd' || myvar == 'nein'){
            component.find("attributeid").set("v.disabled", false);
        }
            else{
                component.find("attributeid").set("v.disabled", true);
            }
```

For the record i already set `disabled="true"` in cmp

but somehow in the first call it ignores it

**EDIT 2**: Solved

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do this with a simple inline check. Try:

```
<lightning:input disabled="{# if(and(v.yourObject.Field__c != 'n/a',
                                     v.yourObject.Field__c != 'none' ), true, false )}" 
                value="{!v.yourObject.Field__c}" 
                label="Your Field Name" />
```

This assumes you have just one sobject and you are not in a loop.

**Edit**: to prevent the inline calculation from evaluating once you start editing (and becoming disabled), you can use the one time binding expression `#` instead of the `!` version that is often used. Note the change in the code: `disabled="{# if(...`

Comment: hello Caspar thank you for your reply, this works ineed but if i delete for example an "a" from "n/a" the field locks assuming its not "n/a" anymore and its getting a "n/" instead so it locks up, how can i correct this?

Comment: See my edit for the solution to this :)

Comment: Hello Caspar, thanks for your reply. In this case `#` its not working for me, first because if i brought an sobject the `#` let me edit the fields ignoring whatever is `none` or not, till i edit, the field blocks. Secondly if i already edit a field and brought another sobject (this action is fired by a search button to call api) all fields are blocked whatever is `n/a` or not. So we are at the beginning. Another possible solution? I thought about using JS but don't know how to vinculate them.